# Why aws express lambda can't invoke pure lambda fucntion?

Tags: node.js, express, aws-lambda, stripe-payments, http-status-code-502

I am very new in this lambda stuffs.

I have an express app. I have uploaded the app as it is using **claudia** to aws lambda.

I have anothe app that is pure lambda app.

When I invoke the pure lambda function from my express app in local host, it works.

But when I call it form the express lambda function, it returns a 502 error.

I am not understanding the issue. Is it happening because I have uploaded the express app as it is(all other apis/end-points are working) or is there any configuration issue?

**Contorller**

```
exports.paywithcard = async (req,res,next) =>{
    let obj
    try{ 
        
       
        
        obj = await StripeService.payMoney(req.body)
        obj = JSON.parse(obj.body)
        req.body.paid_id = obj.charge.id
       
            res.json({
                message: "Payment Successful",
                success: true,
                updatedAsset:assetResponse[0]
        })
    

    }
    catch(err){
       
        res.json({
            message: "Rejected",
            success: false,
    })
    }
```

**the service file where I invoke the pure lambda function

```
exports.payMoney = async(user)=>{
    return await new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
        const params = {
            FunctionName:'stripe_payment',
            Payload: JSON.stringify({
                user
            })
        }
        console.log(params," paramsssssssssss")
        lambda.invoke(params,(err,results)=>{
            console.log(err," err and resultssssssssssssssssss ")
            if(err) reject(err)
            else {
                //console.log("results ",results," results")
                 let res_obj = JSON.parse(results.Payload)
                 //obj = JSON.parse(obj.body)
                //  obj = JSON.parse(obj.charge)
                 //console.log(obj.charge.id,)
                 resolve(res_obj)
                 //return obj.charge.id
                
            }
        })
    })
}
```

The pure Lambda function that has been being invoked

```
const stripe = require("stripe")(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_TEST)
exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
  console.log("Hello worls!!!!!")
  const requestBody = event.user;
  console.log((requestBody," request body !!!!!!!!!"))
  const token = requestBody.id;
  const amount = requestBody.amount;
  const currency = "USD";
  const customer = requestBody.customer
  console.log("req body",requestBody)

  return stripe.paymentIntents.create({ // Create Stripe charge with token
    amount,
    currency,
    description: 'Serverless Stripe Test charge',
    payment_method: token,
    customer,
    confirm: true
  })
    .then((charge) => { // Success response
      console.log(charge," charge")
      const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        headers: {
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'https://stage-back.eidverse.io',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          message: `Charge processed succesfully!`,
          charge,
        }),
       "isBase64Encoded": false,
      };
      callback(null, response);
    })
    .catch((err) => { // Error response
    console.log(err,"err charge")
      const response = {
        statusCode: 500,
        headers: {
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          error: err.message,
        }),
      };
      callback(null, response);
    })
};
```

There is no try catch issue in the console log.

**Task timed out after 6.01 seconds**

Please let me know if any other information I have missed to share. Thank you.

Comment: Please update your question with the error logs from AWS/Cloudwatch.  You may also want to take a look and see if this is related to the issue you're experiencing: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/malformed-502-api-gateway/

Comment: updated. Not working.

Comment: Use aws console and write whole project there. It should solve the issue.

Comment: `async (event, context, callback) ` - remove `async`, `return stripe.paymentIntents.create(` - remove `return`.